# Message sequencing in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka and this is my first post here so please bear with me ;)

We are POC'ing Kafka at the moment for our use cases. I am running a POC test and am perplexed by the below results. I am sure I've missed some sort of a configuration, that is resulting in this, but please can someone have a look and suggest what am I missing:

- I've got a simple Java producer (JAVA PRODUCER code snippet below)
- And a simple Java consumer (JAVA CONSUMER code snippet below)
- I've got 3 broker cluster, with one topic "test-input", partitions=1 and replication-factor=3
- And a Chaos script that stops the broker with the leader partition and one other random broker (every 5 mins). It then restarts the stopped brokers after 3 mins of stoppage
- Both the producer and consumer use the property to connect to all 3 brokers ...    config.put("bootstrap.servers","10.11.29.187:9092,10.11.29.188:9092,10.11.29.189:9092");

**JAVA PRODUCER code snippet:**

```
for(long i=1; i <= 1000000; i++)  
{  
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test-input", null, Long.toString(i)));  
        Thread.sleep(10);  
}
```

**JAVA CONSUMER code snippet:**

```
long saveLong=0;  
String saveRec=null;  
while (true) {  
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));  
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {  
        long thisLong = Long.parseLong(record.value());  
        System.out.println(record.value());  
        if((thisLong - saveLong)!=1){  
                System.out.println("unexpected values between old record >"+saveRec+"< and new record >"+record.value()+"<");  
        }  
        saveLong = thisLong;  
        saveRec = record.value();  
    }  
}
```

My expectations:

- when the Chaos script stops the leading broker, both the producer and
  consumer will connect to the remaining broker
- and ALL the records will be received by the consumer
- and the records will be received in the order published by the producer

HOWEVER, the consumer produces the below. And I am unable to figure out what is causing the out of sequence messages? Will greatly appreciate any sort of help, many thanks in advance!

8729
8730
8731
8732
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=null] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=151689261, epoch=8758) to node 1: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException.
8733
8737
unexpected values between old record >8733< and new record >8737<
8736
unexpected values between old record >8737< and new record >8736<
8735
unexpected values between old record >8736< and new record >8735<
8734
unexpected values between old record >8735< and new record >8734<
8733
unexpected values between old record >8734< and new record >8733<
8738
unexpected values between old record >8733< and new record >8738<
8739
8740
8741
8742

...
...

46233
46234
46235
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=null] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=93331214, epoch=6687) to node 1: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException.
46236
46240
unexpected values between old record >46236< and new record >46240<
46239
unexpected values between old record >46240< and new record >46239<
46238
unexpected values between old record >46239< and new record >46238<
46237
unexpected values between old record >46238< and new record >46237<
46236
unexpected values between old record >46237< and new record >46236<
46241
unexpected values between old record >46236< and new record >46241<
46242
46243
46244
46245

Comment: set max.in.flight.requests.per.connection to 1 in the producer config and check if it works. Ref: https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html. If it's more than 1 messages get re-ordered

Comment: Not that it matters, but you could use the LongSerializer for the value

Comment: many thanks A.Dev and Cricket

Comment: @shma did it work?